# How to check whether the WhereParameters of an EntityDataSource returns 0 rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourcePersoneel"
            runat="server"
            ConnectionString="name=HotelTestDatabaseEntities"
            DefaultContainerName="HotelTestDatabaseEntities"
            EntitySetName="Personeels"
            Include="Afdeling">
   </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I dynamically add these WhereParameters:

```
EntityDataSourcePersoneel.WhereParameters.Clear();
   EntityDataSourcePersoneel.AutoGenerateWhereClause = true;
   EntityDataSourcePersoneel.WhereParameters.Add("personeelID", TypeCode.Int32  
   personeelId.ToString());
```

How can I check if WhereParameters returns 0 rows (nothing)?

Oh yeah, if my code is wrong, please help and advise me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OnSelected` event which will occur after a query has finished executing:

```
protected void EntityDataSourcePersoneel_OnSelected(object Sender, EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.TotalRowCount == 0)
     {
          //Whatever
     }
}
```

Read more: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.selected.aspx)

Comment: Provide more info, what happened? What was the value of `TotalRowCount`? Did you recieve any errors? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You mean the event isn't firing?

Comment: yep.. it won't go into the method

Comment: There's likely a problem elsewhere in your code then. This does exactly what you want.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZvBEfS4D this is the code behind.. http://pastebin.com/XuR1Vtie and this the markup..

Comment: The `OnSelected="EntityDataSourcePersoneel_OnSelected"` goes on the `EntityDataSource` control, not the GridView. Change your markup.

Comment: haha oh yeah lol.. didnt see it thnx :) ill accept ur answer right away !

Comment: No problem, thought it would be something simple like that.